# How to convert the spring checkbox tag to struts2 checkbox?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, struts2

I have a problem while converting the spring check box tag to struts...

I have checkbox tag written in spring which i need to convert it into struts using the values coming from database into the pojo the check box shuld be enabled and disabled according to that.. 

Following  is the code fragment on checkbox in spring:

```
<c:forEach  var="menuList" items="${roleMenuActionMappingBean.menuList}" varStatus="status">
    <form:checkbox path="menuList[${status.index}].active"  id="a_${menuList.getMenuKey()}" value="${menuList.getMenuKey()}"/>
    <form:hidden path="menuList[${status.index}].menuKey" value="${menuList.getMenuKey()}"/>
```

And also what is this:-

```
menuList[${status.index}]
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${menuList.getViewCheckBoxDisabled().equals('true')}">
        <p><form:checkbox path="menuList[${status.index}].viewCheckBox" id="v_${menuList.getMenuKey()}" value="${menuList.getMenuKey()}"/></p>
    </c:when> 
    <c:otherwise>
        <p><form:checkbox path="menuList[${status.index}].viewCheckBox"  id="v_${menuList.getMenuKey()}" value="${menuList.getMenuKey()}" disabled="true"/></p>
    </c:otherwise>    
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Have you checked the relevant tag reference in http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/checkbox.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating from **SpringMVC**(+**JSTL**) to **Struts 2**:

1. - Spring MVC checkbox :

     ```
     <form:checkbox/>
     ```
   - Struts 2 checkbox :

     ```
     <s:checkbox/>
     ```
   - <kbd>[Single CHECKBOX example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/)</kbd>
2. - Spring MVC multiple checkboxes :

     ```
     <form:checkboxes/>
     ```
   - Struts 2 multiple checkboxes :

     ```
     <s:checkboxList/>
     ```
   - <kbd>[multiple CHECKBOXES example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/)</kbd>
3. - JSTL forEach  :

     ```
     <c:forEach>
     ```
   - Struts 2 Iterator :

     ```
     <s:iterator>
     ```
   - <kbd>[ITERATOR example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-iterator-tag-example/)</kbd>
4. - JSTL WHEN and OTHERWISE:

     ```
     <c:when>
        <!-- stuff -->
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
        <!-- stuff -->
     </c:otherwise>
     ```
   - Struts 2 IF and ELSE :

     ```
     <s:if>
        <!-- stuff -->
     </s:if>
     <s:else>
        <!-- stuff -->
     </s:else>
     ```
   - <kbd>[IF ELSE example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-if-elseif-else-tag-example/)</kbd>