# Is there a equivalent to struts form tag iterator in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts2

In struts2 i have found below tag useful when iterating through a collection.

`<s:iterator value="rateList" var="rate" >`

I want to know **if there is an equivalent to this in SPRING** So far as i have searched i could not find one (at least the netbeans codeassist  & websearch does not show).

in my struts project i used the below code to display data in table...

`

```
<%if (i % 2 == 0) {%>
<tr><td> <s:property value="process"/></td><td><s:property value="state"/></td>
<td><s:property value="country"/></td><td><s:property value="vendorCost"/> <td><s:property value="listPrice"/></td>
</td><td><s:date name="lastUpdatedDate" format="dd-MM-yyyy" /></td>
<td><A HREF='updatePrice?id=<s:property value="id"/>'/>Update</A></td>
<td><A HREF='deactivatePrice?id=<s:property value="id"/>'/>Deactivate</A></td>
</tr> 

<%} else {%>
<tr class="alt"><td> <s:property value="process"/></td><td><s:property value="state"/></td>
<td><s:property value="country"/></td><td><s:property value="vendorCost"/></td> <td><s:property value="listPrice"/></td>
<td><s:date name="lastUpdatedDate" format="dd-MM-yyyy" /></td>
<td><A HREF='updatePrice?id=<s:property value="id"/>'/>Update</A></td>
<td><A HREF='deactivatePrice?id=<s:property value="id"/>'/>Deactivate</A></td>
</tr> `
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19541951/1654265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring doesn't have tags that already exist in the JSP Standard Tag Library ([JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)):

```
<c:forEach var="rate" items="${rateList}">

</c:forEach>
```

Note that you should never use scriptlets in JSPs. Use the EL, the JSTL and custom tags (like Spring tags) instead.

To know the current index in the loop and set a CSS class based on the value of the index, you can use

```
<c:forEach var="rate" items="${rateList}" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? '' : 'alt'}">
        ...
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that CSS3 is perfectly able to apply a style to odd rows of a table without the need to add a specific class to every odd row:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) > td 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I used scriplets to introduce class="alt" every alternative row for the CSS to have effect(i want rows in my table to alternate colors). Is there another way to do that without using scriplets??

Comment: It showed error.. then i changed it to ** <tr class="${loopStatus.count % 2 == 0 ? '' : 'alt'}">**  and it worked

Comment: Sorry for that. count or index will indeed both do. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html for all the properties available on the loopStatus object.